# Why do I get an endless loop in my function?

Tags: java, loops, fibonacci

Ok I'm trying to program a program which will output every Fibonacci number. However my numbers will always start at fib(2) and I will use next() to get the next Fibonacci number.

```
public class Fibonacci {
static int NextCounter = 2; // fib(2)
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Enter your number!");
    try {
        FibonacciPrint(System.in.read());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void FibonacciPrint (int a){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a ; i++ ){ 
        System.out.println(next()); // Will never stop? 
    }
}

private static int next() {
    int result = fibo(NextCounter);
    NextCounter += 1;
    return result; 
}

private static int fibo (int n){
    if( n == 1 || n == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return fibo(n-1) + fibo (n-2);
}

}
```

So I'm expecting that the for-loop will stop when i would be equal to a. As you maybe already know it won't. Why ? next() and fibo() are working correctly. Thank you for helping.

Results after a run which I stopped after a second:

```
Enter your number!
5 // Input
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
6765
10946
17711
28657
46368
75025
121393
196418
317811
514229
832040
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
9227465
14930352
24157817
39088169
63245986
102334155
```

Comment: First and foremost, your code should **never** have: `catch (IOException e) {}` -- empty catch blocks, **ever**. Do you drive your car with your eyes closed?

Comment: Does it print anything? What's the value of `a`? Have you tried stepping through it?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, I will get every Fibonacci number. A should be the user Input.

Comment: Yes, but what *is* the value of `a`? Set a breakpoint, inspect the code!

Comment: I note that inspecting the value of `a` at runtime would have revealed the problem that @Paul points out in his answer below - debugging is an important skill to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `System.in.read()`. This reads a `byte`. If you enter `8` for example, the character `'8'` will get converted to the `int` value `56` and your program will compute 56 fibonacci numbers (very slowly because you do not use memoization).

Try

```
FibonacciPrint(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt());
```

instead.

Comment: Oh yes! you are right. This is working now. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem - glad I could help.